# Using Native Tkinter on mac, not X11 Tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, x11, anaconda

I have been using the native python and tkinter applications (python2.7) on Mac OSX 10.7

I recently installed anaconda for the incredible selection of mathematical packages, however, Tkinter now used x11 and crashes constantly and is extremely ugly.  [I saw this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045631/use-no-x11-tkinter-with-python-installed-through-macports) and don't fully understand it. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds and use my anaconda install but not have to use x11 for Tkinter?